# Does RocksDB collapse merge arguments during reads if PartialMerge is specified

Tags: rocksdb

Both RocksDB [dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rocksdb) and FB [page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/rocksdb.dev) seems unresponsive so I'm asking the question here.

I'm wondering if RocksDB collapses merge arguments on every read of PartialMerge operator is specified?
Particularly the use case looks like this:

1. There is a single column db which stores a number
2. Both FullMerge/PartialMerge operators are specified and simply computing the sum of values.
3. We write a key/value pairs: ("some_key", 1), ("some_key", 1), ("some_key", 1).
   3') No compaction happened here
4. We read the value for key "some_key": I expected 3 reads to occur returning the value 3.
5. We read again the value for key "some_key": here is the question if rocksdb will perform 1 or 3 reads?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, rocksdb merges the value on the read path - so the second read would only be 1 read - since the value has already been merged/collapsed

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Do you have any doc/code pointers to look at to make sure of it?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/issues/4667#issuecomment-440405196